# Trying to setData to clipboard from ListTile (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, clipboard

I am trying to get the data that came from database and set it to clipboard from ListTile. when I click to an icon in AppBar (Content copy icon) I want to copy the text showing in the screen for the users.
I tried many ways but didn't work and after many tries I couldn't do that.

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

**The code**

```
import 'package:bornmonth/entity/BornMonth.dart';
import 'package:bornmonth/entity/Month.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:rich_clipboard/rich_clipboard.dart';

class maintexts extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hint;
  final int id;
  const maintexts({super.key, required this.hint, required this.id});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: texts(hinttext: hint, id: id,),
    );
  }
}


class texts extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hinttext;
  final int id;
  const texts({super.key, required this.hinttext, required this.id});

  @override
  State<texts> createState() => _textsState();
}

class _textsState extends State<texts> {
  List<bornmonth> _list = [];
  String text="";


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadData();
  }

  _loadData() async {
    await Month.getMain(widget.id).then((list) {
      setState(() {
        _list = list;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.blueAccent),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
          title: Text("طالع بینی ${widget.hinttext}", style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  
                  ClipboardData? cdata = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('Copied to your clipboard !'));
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.copy,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                )),
          ],

        ),
          body: _list.isNotEmpty
              ? ListView.separated(
                itemCount: _list.length,
                itemBuilder: (c, index) {
                  if(widget.hinttext=="کلی"){
                    return Material(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(_list[index].main),
                            // Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: "your text"));
                        ),


                      );

                  }

          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
        )
            : const Center(child: SizedBox(width: 50, height: 50, child: CircularProgressIndicator())),

        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are seeing?

Comment: Take a look to the code please!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're on the right track with Clipboard.setData, but you can't just toss it into the title parameter of ListTile. It's like trying to sneak a cat into a dog party - it's just not gonna fly. Instead, you gotta make it so when the user taps on the ListTile , that's when we slip the data into the clipboard. Kinda like a secret handshake, ya know?

Have a gander at this updated code snippet:

```
return Material(
  color: Colors.white ,
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text(_list[index].main) ,
    onTap: () {
      Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: _list[index].main));
    } ,
  ) ,
);
```

In this version, onTap is where the magic happens. When the ListTile gets a tap , it fires off an asynchronous operation to set the clipboard data to your text. Just like a well-trained magician's assistant.

Comment: I don't want to tap on text, I want when the data load it set to clipboard automatically.